# IIS6 access parent folder of the app home folder

Tags: .net, iis-6, windows-server-2003

Well. i'm really sorry for the fact that this question is easily testable, but i need to plan this for tomorrow and i don't have the means to test it now. I'm willing to lose the reputation if you are willing to help me out.

Scenario: i got

-iis wwwroot
   - domainfolder (DynamicWeb Instalation)
        - destinationfolder
   - subdomain folder
          default.aspx

I need to know if i can make a fileupload in my Default.aspx, and do something like:

```
fileUpload.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("../domainfolder/destinationfolder/") + filename)
```

keep in mind that I will have full access to the windows server where the sites are hosted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your IIS worker user needs write permissions on the target directory, and AspEnableParentPaths needs to be set to "true", but other than that it should just work.

Comment: Be careful with the "filename" portion though. Ideally you're going to want to generate it on your server.

Comment: thanx martona, i will test it tomorrow, i will mark it as answer if it works. As for the filename i got it covered :), thanks again

Comment: Also... AspEnableParentPaths needs to be set to "true". I think it's off by default even on IIS6. (BTW, we're migrating to IIS8 right now...)